# How to valid @RequestHeader in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, spring-boot

How can I verify required header if it's missing or wrong format?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/example/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)        
    public ResponseEntity<> update(@RequestHeader(value="last-modified-date") String lastModDate, HttpServletRequest request,
                @RequestBody ReBody rebody, @PathVariable("id") int id) throws Exception{
    // Stuff here...
    }
```

the format of "lastModDate" likes "Mon, 28 Aug 2017 02:51:09 GMT"

I would like to do some custom validation on the header attribute i.e.

```
if (lastModDate == null) {
    throw Exception();
}
```

or throw the exception when it's in the wrong format.

Comment: And why not do it in the //Stuff here.... part?

Comment: This is two separate questions. If the header is missing, your String will indeed be null. Validation is really up to you but one possible way is to define the exact format you'd like and try extracting it with [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: because it will throw null point exception before run the code "//stuff" when the header is empty. Right now the format is been well defined, but when the format is not correct, it throws null point too

Comment: @xiao Are you passing lastModDate as string . I would suggest you to send date in timestamp or ISO date String not as string like this :`Mon, 28 Aug 2017 02:51:09 GMT`

Answer (score 0):

You already answered to your question. You can simply do it like below:-

```
public ResponseEntity<> update(@RequestHeader(value="last-modified-date") String lastModDate, HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody ReBody rebody, @PathVariable("id") int id) throws Exception{

         if (lastModDate == null) {
         throw Exception();
         }

         // Stuff here...

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@Valid` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)        
public ResponseEntity<> update(@Valid @RequestHeader(value="last-modified-date") String lastModDate, HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody ReBody rebody, @PathVariable("id") int id) throws Exception{
    // Stuff here...
}
```

But you still will need to manually perform format validation. Or change your `lastModDate` type from `String` to `Date` or convert it to `timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @Valid and @Pattern

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/example/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)        
public ResponseEntity<> update(@RequestHeader(value="last-modified-date", required = true) @Pattern(regexp =  "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$") String lastModDate, HttpServletRequest request,
                @RequestBody ReBody rebody, @PathVariable("id") int id) throws Exception{
    // Stuff here...
}
```

Comment: You could point to some [tutorial on bean validation with spring-boot](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/) or mention some keywords to look up these annotations of package `javax.validation` or the concept _bean validation_ in general.